# Adding numbers in PHP

Tags: php

If I had a string containing the following, is it possible to add all the numbers up and remove the commas?

```
$string = "1,2,3,4,5,6,";
```

I have tried a few options, but can't figure out how.

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried explode? use that on the comma in the string. The result is a array with the numbers

Comment: explode() and array_sum()

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try this:

```
$string = "1,2,3,4,5,6,";
echo array_sum(explode(',', $string));
```

And the answer is 21

Answer (score 2):

This php should do the trick:
`array_sum(explode(',', $string));`

This code first uses `explode()` which splits up your string into an array splitting the second parameter using the character identified by the first parameter.

Then since you have an array you are getting the sum `array_sum()` of the enclosed array, which in this case is the string you just split.

References:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php
http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Edit: Since there were similar duplicate answers I further expanded upon my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
$tmp = explode(',', $string); //Split the string on the commas

$sum = 0;

//Loop over the numbers and add them to $tmp
foreach ($tmp as $number)
{
  $sum = $sum + $number;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or, more drawn out version:

```
$string = "1,2,3,4,5,6,";
$sum = 0;

foreach(explode(',', $string) as $num)
{
    $sum += $num;
}
echo $sum;
```

Comment: `foreach` what? You don't have an array in your code?

Comment: The `explode` method will create the array.  Try copy and pasting it here http://writecodeonline.com/php/

Comment: Fair enough.  I’m used to `$array = range(1, 6);` then `foreach ($array as $number)`. Much cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$values = array();
$sum = 0;

$values = explode(',', $string);

foreach($values as $value)
{
    $sum = $sum + $value;
}

echo $sum;
```